# Sharing volumes but overwriting files and not replacing the whole folder

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm trying to set up a docker image for a NodeJs project. It has so many dependencies and it takes a long time to set them up. I would like to have a docker image with all the necessary libraries and even the source code which I can run easily:

```
docker run -it --rm my_image
```

In fact, I've already got this. But the problem is that I'm developing the code and I need to copy the code into the container frequently. Currently, I'm doing so using `docker cp`. But since there are lots of files, I was hoping I could use something like volumes instead:

```
docker run -it --rm \
    -v $(pwd)/project:/root/project \
    my_image
```

But this will replace the whole folder and the `node_modules` is not there anymore. And I have to run `npm i` again (which takes a long time to finish). I was wondering is there a way to overwrite the content of the folder instead of replacing it?

Comment: Arrange things so that the parts that should come from the image and the parts that should come from outside are in different folders. Maybe using symlinks would help.

Comment: I'd suggest using a local Node environment for day-to-day development.  If the code inside the image changes, you need to `docker build` a new image.  Volumes are not intended for code, and there is no "merge files" operation when mounting a volume (it works the same as if you mounted a USB drive over your host's source directory).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up moving my code into a subfolder and replace that folder by mounting a volume:

```
docker run -it --rm \
    -v $(pwd)/project/src:/root/project/src \
    my_image
```

That was I'm not replacing the `node_modules` folder anymore.